# Create a double check within a if condition

Tags: php

I am creating some application, facebook application and i need to ask you something.

I retrieve the like_friend variable by using this code:

```
if(!empty($friends['data'])){
        $like_friend = $facebook->api(array(
                    "method" => "fql.query",
                    "query"  => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='".$page_id."' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"));
        $check_arr = array();
        if(!empty($like_friend)){
            foreach($like_friend as $likes){
                $check_arr[] = $likes['uid'];
            }
        }

        $like_friend_other = $facebook->api(array(
                    "method" => "fql.query",
                    "query"  => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=184759054887922 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"));
        $check_arr1 = array();
        if(!empty($like_friend_other)){
            foreach($like_friend_other as $likes){
                $check_arr[] = $likes['uid'];
            }
        }


        $size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
        $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
        foreach($friends['data'] as $data){
            if(!in_array($data['id'],$check_arr) && in_array($data['id'],$check_arr1)){
```

If i just duplicate it but name it $like_friend1 can i do a double check like this:

```
if(!in_array($data['id'],$check_arr) && in_array($data['id'],$check_arr1)){
```

Comment: I need to check first friends who don't like a page id then i need to do a double search for friends who don't like this specific id but like other pages id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes.

In cases like this, the best way is to simply try it and see what happens ;)

Comment: Can you please see my updated check, i can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong here.... because i don't get the result i need to, it comes out blank!

Comment: Within your second look, you're still using `$check_arr`, not `$check_arr1`

Comment: Oh my god, i made it work :D
Thanks, i don't have my glasses right now, i don't see :D, thanks!